# What is "fxs" in (obsolete) JavaScript method names?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, naming

Sometimes in legacy code I can see method with "addSomethingFxs" and it's supposed to be used for animations, effects, transitions - UI effects in general. The specific one was found actually in jQuery project.

Is there any meaning for "fxs"? Was looking for it in CSS/Front-End/Graphic Design/JavaScript topics, but can't find it anywhere.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FX https://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

Comment: @Bergi so it'll mean "effect" most probably then - based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FX (Effects unit, Guitar effects...). Doesn't answer my question, but I can conclude based on these links that it means "effects". Therefore, let keep this question closed. Thanks.